# CAKEPHP: Filter Issues

Tags: cakephp, filter

http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/clients

PROBLEM: http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/timesheets/filter2/7

This has to be an issue with a lowercase variable or something, but I just cannot figure it out. 
Filter2.ctp
    
    
    IDnameHoursclientsedit

```
<? foreach($Timesheets as $row): ?>
     <tr><td>
<?=$row['Timesheet']['id']?>
</td><td>
<?=$row['Timesheet']['hours']?>
</td><td>
<a href="../../clients/view/<?=$row['client']['name']?>"><?=$row['client]['name']?></a>
</td><td>
<a href="edit/<?=$row['Timesheet']['id']?>">Edit</a>
    </td></tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Timesheetcontroller filter2

```
function filter2($Client_id) {
        $this->set('Timesheets',$this->Timesheet->findAllByClientId($Client_id));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
<a href="../../clients/view/<?=$row['client']['name']?>"><?=$row['client]['name']?></a>
```

You are missing a `'`. This is producing the syntax error. You will probably also need to capitalize the `'Client'` index to get the desired result, as it is the name of a model. It is also likely that the `view` action in `ClientsController` expects an id. You can change it to:

```
<a href="../../clients/view/<?=$row['Client']['id']?>"><?=$row['Client']['name']?></a>
```

However, I would suggest not to hardcode the url like that, but have Cake produce the link like so:

```
<?= $this->Html->link($row['Client']['name'], array('controller' => 'clients', 'action' => 'view', $row['Client']['id']) ?>
```

See the [docs on helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html), as well as the [HtmlHelper API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/html-helper).